# Django Data in Form Not Showing Up With POST

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-templates, django-views

I currently have an UpdateView and a button to edit data in fields, but for some reason the data is not being displayed when I click my edit button. It shows a bunch of empty fields unless I go to the address bar and press enter, basically requesting the same page. Then all the data shows up.

Doesn't work when I click Edit, works when I press enter in address bar:

```
/inventory/update/7/
```

views.py

```
class ProductUpdate(UpdateView):
model = Product
fields = [
    'manufacturer',
    'part_number',
    'description',
    'vendor',
    'upc',
    'stock_quantity',
    'unit_cost',
    'sale_price',
]
```

urls.py

```
# /inventory/update/<pk>
    url(r'update/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/$', views.ProductUpdate.as_view(), name='product-update'),
```

index.html

```
<div class="col-sm-6">
    <ul class="list-group">
        {% for product in all_products %}
            <li class="list-group-item">
                <a href="{% url 'inventory:product_detail' product.id %}"><span style="font-size: 1.6em;">{{ product.manufacturer }}: {{ product.part_number }}</span></a>

                <form action="{% url 'inventory:product-delete' product.id %}" method="post" style="display: inline">
                {% csrf_token %}
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm float-right" style="margin-left: 10px; margin-top: 4px;">Delete</button>
                </form>

                <form action="{% url 'inventory:product-update' product.id %}" method="post" style="display: inline">
                {% csrf_token %}
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-warning btn-sm float-right" style="margin-top: 4px;">Edit</button>
                </form>
             </li>  
        {% endfor %}
    </ul>
</div>
```

If I change the update form method to `GET` instead of `POST`then it works when I click the button, but my address bar shows up like this.

```
/inventory/update/7/?csrfmiddlewaretoken=34WWjKDIDsNpZdmEmef9cr3tCoCO0V7jO3uks5qXFzSVKu1uAklqUA3ihaGBGaRK
```

I also tried using the `{{ form.as_p }}` with `POST` but that did not make the data show up either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I can understand(pardon me if I got it wrong), the **Edit** button inside your *index.html* serves the purpose of getting you an edit form with initial data(pre-filled) of a model instance(Product).

If the button is there to simply fetch a form of **UpdateView** then,

why are you putting the edit button inside the `<form>` tag with `method="post"`in the first place? The Edit button simply needs to bring the information stored inside a model instance.

Besides this, why do you need a **POST request** to **get** the form for updating a product(model = Product).

For getting the information, it's unwise to use a **POST** request.

**Another Note** I hope you realize that `{% csrf_token %}` token are only meant for **POST** requests. There is no need for `{% csrf_token %}` at all.

When you just need a URL like: `/inventory/update/7` then why not use an `<a>` tag instead?

Try this:

```
<div class="col-sm-6">
<ul class="list-group">
    {% for product in all_products %}
        <li class="list-group-item">
            <a href="{% url 'inventory:product_detail' product.id %}"><span style="font-size: 1.6em;">{{ product.manufacturer }}: {{ product.part_number }}</span></a>

            <a href="{% url 'inventory:product-delete' product.id %}">Delete</a>

            <a href="{% url 'inventory:product-update' product.id %}">Edit</a>
         </li>  
    {% endfor %}
</ul>
</div>
```

I hope this helps you. Correct me if I got your problem incorrectly. Thanks.

Comment: Holy dumb I didn't even realize! This works perfectly and is the answer to my question! I was thinking I needed to use a form to request data...